# a href span and img not working

Tags: image, html

The link does not work at all, does anyone know what is wrong?

```
<div id="projectsCol">
<ul>
<li style="height: 80px;" id="fbrd_01" class="project int">
<a href="http://www.godsremnantassembly.org/missions/what-we-do.html">
<span class="title"><strong style="height: 49px;">Missions Resources</strong></span>
<img src="index_files/thumb-alfred.jpg" alt="">
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

***Thank you all. More info is that clicking the image does not return the linked page. Here is the site http://www.godsremnantassembly.org.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what's not working, and what it's meant to be doing? It works for me.

Comment: It's working for me.  Can you post all of your code?

Comment: Thank you all. More info is that clicking the image does not return the required linked page. Here is the site [http://www.godsremnantassembly.org](http://www.godsremnantassembly.org). @Hiigaran

Answer (score 0):

I just created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CyD4/) for this and it works just fine.

JSFiddle recommended adding a / at the end of the  tag like so:

```
<img src=..." />
```